# How to extract domain name using dynamic regex in Redshift?

Tags: regex, postgresql, url, amazon-redshift

I need to extract domain name from url using Redshift PostgreSQL. Example : extract 'google.com' from 'www.google.com'. Each url in my dataset has different top level domain (TLD). My approach was to first join the matching TLD to the dataset and use regex to extract 'first_string.TLD'. In Redshift, I'm getting error 'The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression'. Is there a way around this?

A sample of my dataset:

```
 +---+------------------------+--------------+
 | id|    trimmed_domain      |  tld         |
 +---+------------------------+--------------+
 | 1 | sample.co.uk           | co.uk        |
 | 2 | www.sample.co.uk       | co.uk        |
 | 3 | www3.sample.co.uk      | co.uk        |
 | 4 | biz.sample.co.uk       | co.uk        |
 | 5 | digital.testing.sam.co | co           |
 | 6 | sam.co                 | co           |
 | 7 | www.google.com         | com          |
 | 8 | 1.11.220               |              |
 +---+------------------------+--------------+
```

My code:

```
 SELECT t1.extracted_domain, COUNT(DISTINCT(t1.id))
 FROM(
     SELECT 
     d.id,
     d.trimmed_domain,
     CASE 
     WHEN d.tld IS null THEN d.trimmed_domain ELSE 
      regexp_replace(d.trimmed_domain,'(.*\.)((.[a-z]*).*'||replace(tld,'.','\.')||')','\2') 
     END AS "extracted_domain" 
     FROM dataset d
     )t1
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 2;
```

Expected output:

```
 +------------------------+--------------+
 |    extracted_domain    |  count       |
 +------------------------+--------------+
 | sample.co.uk           | 4            |
 | sam.co                 | 2            |
 | google.com             | 1            |
 | 1.11.220               | 1            |
 +------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found a solution. Redshift does not support column based regex so the alternative is to use Python UDF.

1. Change the tld column to regex pattern.[image: part1]
2. Go row by row and extract the domain name using the regex pattern column. [image: part2]
3. Group by the extracted_domain and count the users.

The SQL query is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function extractor(col_domain varchar)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
    import re
    _regex = ''
    for domain in col_domain:
        if domain is None:
           continue
        else:
           _regex += r'{}'.format(domain)
    domain_regex = r'([^/.]+\.({}))'.format(_regex)
    return domain_regex
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION regex_match(in_pattern varchar, input_str varchar)
RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE AS $$
    import re
    if in_pattern == '':
        a = str(input_str)
    else: 
        a= str(re.search(in_pattern, input_str).group())
    return a
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT 
t2.extracted_domain,
COUNT(DISTINCT(t2.id)) AS "Unique Users"
FROM(
    SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.trimmed_domain,
    regex_match(t1.regex_pattern, t1.trimmed_domain) AS "extracted_domain"
    FROM(
        SELECT 
        id,
        trimmed_domain,
        CASE WHEN tld is null THEN '' ELSE extractor(tld) END AS "regex_pattern"
        FROM dataset
        )t1
    )t2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Python UDF seems to be slow on a large dataset. So, I'm open to suggestions on improving the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sure about the query. However, you can use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/EiE90L/1/) and design any expression that you wish to modify your query.

My guess is that maybe this would help:

```
^(?!d|b|www3).*
```

You can list any domain that you wish to exclude in the list using OR `(?!d|b|www3)`.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

---

You maybe want to add your desired URLs to [an expression similar to](https://regex101.com/r/hmFiaX/1):

```
^(sam|www.google|1.11|www.sample|www3.sample).*
```

[image]

Comment: "You can list any domain that you wish to exclude in the list using OR (?!d|b|www3)". There are too many. I did use this approach in my first version. The list was so long making the code messy.

Comment: I just provided a sample dataset for better visualization of my question. My original dataset has 410 different urls. Will add the sql_related tags too.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prefixes you would like to remove from the domains, then why not just exclude these? The following query simply removes the know www/http/etc prefixes from domain names and counts normalized domain names.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from 
  (select REGEXP_REPLACE(domain, '^(https|http|www|biz)') FROM domains) 
GROUP BY regexp_replace;
```

Comment: I did this for my version 1. The problem is there are way too many prefixes like www3, health, travel, translate, apps, search, life, etc. This method requires constant updating whenever there is a different url. This is why I'm looking for another method.

Comment: Oh, I see - I wanna extract only "something + TLD". Yeah, listing prefixes won't work for such case.